# JSON Web Token (JWT) is too long to pass through client URL? Node.js and Express authentication

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, express-jwt

I am trying to use JWT to authenticate a user's email address. I cannot use OAuth because a user will be signing up with their work email and will need to verify using that.

I have added a field to my User model called isVerified. I have used mailgun to send an email to the user when they go to sign up that includes a link to a verification page in the form of http://{client_url}/verification/{userToken} where the userToken is a generated token using JSON web token.... the token is created using only the user's id so there is not a lot of information in the payload.

When the user clicks on this link, they are getting a 404 Not Found error. When I manually shorten the userToken in the url, then it properly connects to the correct React Component...
How do I solve this issue?

UPDATE: I just got rid of all the periods from the JWT token and it is loading like that.... so it seems to not be an issue with the length but with the periods... My react router Route path is "/verification/:userToken" ... how do I get it to not be affected by the periods?

Comment: What do you mean by manually shorten the userToken in the url, could you provide an example?

Comment: @Helix112 Yes of course, I just mean that the following returns a 404 Error http://localhost:8080/verification/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOjIyLCJpYXQiOjE2MTEwMDY5OTUsImV4cCI6MTYxMTAwODE5NX0.D_-RI_YvE6lyHZFtkMizuHxPs3huIE87D6UKFEywYdg ...... but then when I truncate the JWT part to right before the first period it connects correctly... like this http://localhost:8080/verification/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9

Comment: @Helix112 Oh wow I just got rid of all the periods from the JWT token and it is loading like that.... so it seems to not be an issue with the length but with the periods... My react router Route path is "/verification/:userToken" ... do you know how I would get it to not be affected by the periods?

Comment: the second token is not a valid JWT. Does the "." in the token prevent the url from matching your "verification/token" route ? I mean like that in react "verification/string1.string2" is not a valid route. Try calling for example "verification/test.test.test" and see if it renders your component. For the dates stuff, I don't know what's going on, but I think it is more about your code in react and how you encode/decode the token than a problem with the jwt itself. Posting your code would help.

Comment: @Helix112 hi thanks for your reply. the issue turned out being that my webpack was not allowing the dots to be read correctly in the URL, so I just used a helper function to replace the "." with "%dot%" and then did the opposite when reading the jwt back from the url. Thanks!

Comment: glad to hear that. I'll redevelop my comment as an answer , please accept it.

Comment: you can also reply to my answer and explain how did you manage to fix it with "%dot%" stuff for whom who reads this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this does not trigger your component to be rendered

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOjIyLCJpYXQiOjE2MTEwMDY5OTUsImV4cCI6MTYxMTAwODE5NX0.D_-RI_YvE6lyHZFtkMizuHxPs3huIE87D6UKFEywYdg

and this does

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9

I would suspect that it somehow worked because you got rid of the dots.

Make sure the "." in the token prevent the url from matching your "verification/token" route ? I mean react is assuming that

> "verification/**ey**xxxx.**ey**zzzz"

is not a valid route.

Try calling for example "`verification/test.test.test`" and see if it renders your component.

Comment: Yes, the dots were the issue. I managed to get rid of them by converting the URL to replace the "." with "%dot%" `const convertToUrl = (jwt) => {
  return jwt.replace(/\./g, '%dot%')
};` and then the reverse to use the token

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the token as a url query parameter.
This means your url should be something like this:

```
http://my website.com?token={userToken}
```

You then get the userToken from the query parameter.